# Determine a file with the most Hard-Links

Tags: hard-link

i got a homework today. Can u help me guys?

"Determine on any PC pool that hosts regular file on the local file system root who has the most hard links! Avoid doing a search of the user home directories or other NFS mounted directories. Type a file name of an regular file, the number of hard links, and a command that you could have a look at all the name of this file!"

With best regards!
Marko

Comment: `/` is the home directory of some system users on many systems. So that assignment is bit confusing. What's a _PC pool_?

Comment: Yeap, i guess we use all the same Home directory. Just everybody gots his account (example: pool14:/home/myusername>

Comment: Where do people get UNIX homework from? lol.

Comment: @DisplayName People like me who teach it :)

Answer (score 0):

**file with most hardlinks**

You can use the commands

1. `find` with the (GNU?) option `-xdev`, and the command `-printf` and its directives `%n` and `%p`
2. `sort -rn`
3. `head -n 1`

Of course, there may be different files (inodes) with the same number of hardlinks. If finding one of them is not enough then the solution becomes more complicated.

**finding the other paths to a file / inode**

You can use the command `find` with the option `-xdev`, and the test `-samefile`.

Comment: So is that the way i can do it in Xterm? Sorry, im still total new to unix/linux. :S

Comment: Yes, these commands are run in a shell like the one running in `xterm`. Hard to believe that you get such homework without being familiar with the basics.

Comment: It´s never late to learn something new! :) But, thx for the answer, it works :)